# CakePHP isAuthorized false returns to same page, rather than redirecting to a URL

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I want to use `isAuthorized` functionality of CakePHP but whenever the access should be denied  user is returned to the page he came from.

The best I could find so far is using `authError-> 'You are denied'` which doesn't even get flashed.

Do I have to set flashes and redirects manually before the `return false;` line in `isAuthorized` function?

Is there a way to check if it was denied and then do a 404 automatically?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to configure your `Auth->loginRedirect`, so that when a user is denied they are pushed to the login page. The Auth component will remember the page that the user was trying to access, and if they login it will redirect them back to that page.

For reference, the configuration of the Auth component is detailed in the book.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

I tend to use the older method of configuring Auth in the `AppController::beforeFilter()`

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);
}
```

Comment: Also check out [exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html) (namely `NotFoundException` if you need a 404), and [`AuthComponent::$unauthorizedRedirect`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::$unauthorizedRedirect) in CakePHP >= 2.3